# Scroll returns to default after display:none in Chrome/IE

Tags: css, scroll, browser, standards, behavior

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/sammy/RubNy/

Scroll down in the div container. Then click anywhere in the window to hide the element. Then click once more to show the element. You'll notice in Chrome/IE that the scroll is reset, but in Firefox, the scroll remains how you left it.

Which is the standards behavior, Chrome/IE or Firefox? Should I report this to the Chrome issue tracker?

Thanks in advance for any help on this, and happy new year, and thanks again, and cheers, and stuff. =D

Comment: I updated your fiddle to test with iframes. As of now, only Firefox does not preserve scroll position after hiding an iframe element.
http://jsfiddle.net/RubNy/30/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm not sure which of the two browsers (Chrome or Firefox) is following the standard on this one, I'll blame Chrome for being incorrect for not "remembering" the scroll position. In other words, I favor Firefox's behavior, but I'm unsure which is correct (standardized).

Until someone points out which is correct according to standard documentation, I'll continue to blame Chrome. I'll report this bug to the Chrome issue tracker if I haven't already. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can save current `element.scrollTop` to some `bufferVar` before `display: none`. When `display: block` you reset `element.scrollTop` back to `bufferVar`.

But this approach won't work immediately for some reasons not obvious to me. Use something like this to make it work:

```
setTimeout(() => { element.scrollTop = bufferVar; }, 100);
```

Comment: It's strange to me why it doesn't work without `setTimeout()`, but with `setTimeout(() => { element.scrollTop = bufferVar; }, 0)` it does.

Comment: I found Chrome jumped down the page after switching between `display:none;` and `display:flex;`. I fixed it with the help of this answer. The timeout made it visibly jump and jump back but it seems to work without a timeout (Chrome v85), like this, `let oldScroll = window.scrollY; pages[j].style.display = "none"; pages[j+1].style.display = "flex"; window.scrollTo(0, oldScroll);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which are right however this works:

```
var offset = 0;
$(document).click(function(){
    if($('div:visible').length) {
        offset = $('div').scrollTop();   
    }
    $('div').toggle().scrollTop(offset);
});
```

I hope somebody has a better solution =/

Comment: The point isn't to find a solution to this issue, but rather point this out to the browser makers. I know I can use visibility instead of display, or -99999px top if position is absolute. But it would be nice if all browsers acted like Firefox in this situation. So I'm going to go report this bug to Chrome, and if Firefox's behavior not standard behavior, then at least I stirred the pot a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a quirk in how the browsers render the div when the display changes...

Essentially, the browsers reflow the text when the display property changes...

This causes the same quirk...

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('div').style.display = "block";
});
```

If you want the scroll to remain the same in all browsers, the easiest thing to use is visibility instead of display...

Comment: I understand that it's the display property that is causing this. But what I want to know is which behavior is the right behavior. I want this reported to those browsers that behave incorrectly.