# Google Chrome - iframe scrolls back to top after display: none

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RubNy/30/

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('div').toggle(); // div scroll is retained
    $('#FileFrame').toggle(); // iframe scroll is not retained
});
```

When an iframe gets hidden using display: none and then get shown back, the scroll position return back to top. Is this behavior standard ? and is there any way to keep the iframe scrolling position ?

I found this behavior on Windows 11 Google Chrome Version 115.0.5790.110 (Official Build) and Edge Version 115.0.1901.188 (Official build) (64-bit). However on Firefox 116.0 (64-bit) the iframe scroll is retained.

Comment: If it is a same-origin iframe, then you should be able to read the current scroll position before you hide it, and set it again when you show it.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, unfortunately I cannot implement such solution, because display none and visibility  hidden have their own difference in behaviour (layouting, etc), and also I'm using a frontend framework to do control the hide/show so having to modify the framework is also another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, different browsers have different behaviors on some sides. Edge and Chrome are both based on chromium, so they have the same behavior. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582669/scroll-returns-to-default-after-displaynone-in-chrome-ie), it seems that the behavior in chromium is standard.

> Essentially, the browsers reflow the text when the display property changes...

Besides, the thread also provide a easy way to keep the iframe scrolling position if you want:

> If you want the scroll to remain the same in all browsers, the easiest thing to use is visibility instead of display...

You can refer to the code below:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('div').toggle();
  $("#FileFrame").css("visibility", function(i, visibility){
      return (visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
    });
});
```